# Running 'vim' at prompt instead of fg

Tags: vim

I am new to using Vim and I just learned how to switch to the foreground, then back into vim.  I am getting confused because I forget if I was in vim and went back to the command line (by command+z), or if I was already on teh command line.  Sometimes I run 'vim' again when I am on the command line but it causes me problems when I do this a few times (on accident, of course).

Is there a best practice for using command+z, then the fg command when on the prompt?  There is no visual indicator and I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried running `jobs` (assuming you're using bash)? It shows you status of the stopped processes ran from the current shell if there are any.

Comment: I would update your `$PS1` prompt (via `$PROMPT_COMMAND`) with an indication of `jobs` and/or `$SHLVL`.

Comment: The jobs command does show every vim instance - thanks.  Please post so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the solution hinted at by Ingo for a few years, now.

Here is a simplified version of my bash prompt:

```
export PS1='$(((SHLVL>1))&&echo $SHLVL" ") \u $ '
```

where the `$(((SHLVL>1))&&echo $SHLVL" ")` part shows the how many times bash was started in the same session.

It should look like this when you didn't mess up with multiple `<C-z>`:

```
username $
```

or like that if you forgot to do `fg` once:

```
2 username $
```

and so on…

Anyway, you should probably investigate terminal multiplexers like screen or tmux.